# SSIS Script Task Excel connection open: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: c#, excel, ssis, dts

I've read about as many articles as I can stand.  Time to ask for help.

I am upgrading SSIS packages from 2008R2 to 2016.  I'm using VS2019 set for 2016.  The script task works fine right up to the line of code that does the `Connection.Open();`

I've tried both providers, same result.  I was using a Package Parameter, but commented that out and hard coded the value.

This is the returned Exception:

> DTS Script Task has encountered an exception in user code:
> Project name: ST_6bceaa360e1d4200a203f7c688acd0fd
> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
> invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder
> binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers,
> CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
> at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()

Here is the code I'm using:

```
    public void Main()
    {
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;

        string sFile;
        OleDbConnection connection;
        string sConnectionString;
        int dataloop = 0;

        //sFile = Dts.Variables["$Project::InputFilePath01"].Value.ToString();
        sFile = @"C:\AccknowledgeData\InvoiceXLS.xls";

        if (File.Exists(sFile))
        {
            if (File.GetAttributes(sFile) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly)
            {
                //File.SetAttributes(sFile, FileAttributes.Normal);
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
                return;
            }

            //sConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + sFile + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0";
            sConnectionString = @"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + sFile + @";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;HDR=NO";
            using (connection = new OleDbConnection(sConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                try
                {
                    DataTable tables = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                    while (dataloop < tables.Rows.Count)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            DataRow table = tables.Rows[dataloop];
                            OleDbDataAdapter cmdLoadExcel = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select count(*) from [" + table["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() + "]", connection);
                            DataSet ldExcelDS = new DataSet();
                            cmdLoadExcel.Fill(ldExcelDS);
                            if (ldExcelDS.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString() != "0")
                            {
                                Dts.Variables["User::Tab"].Value = table["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                                dataloop = tables.Rows.Count;
                            }
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            dataloop++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
                    Dts.ExecutionValue = "Connection String = " + connection.ConnectionString;
                }
                finally
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance for taking a look.

Richard

Comment: If you used `sConnectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\"{0}\";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR={1};IMEX=1\"", sFile);` does that work? I think the issue is you aren't building your connection string properly. https://billfellows.blogspot.com/2013/04/ssis-excel-source-via-script.html  I have JET and ACE samples in that blog post. And the other thing is to [FireInformation](https://billfellows.blogspot.com/2016/04/biml-script-task-test-for-echo.html) and log what the actual value of `sConnectionString` is so you compare expected to actual.

Comment: billinkc - That worrked!  Thank you so much.  How do I mark this as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you used `sConnectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\"{0}\";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR={1};IMEX=1\"", sFile);` does that work? I think the issue is you aren't building your connection string properly.

I have JET and ACE samples in this blog post [SSIS Excel Source via Script](https://billfellows.blogspot.com/2013/04/ssis-excel-source-via-script.html)

The other thing is to [FireInformation](https://billfellows.blogspot.com/2016/04/biml-script-task-test-for-echo.html) event and log what the actual value of `sConnectionString` is so you compare expected to actual.

Answer (score 1):

It might be an architecture issue, you are trying to use a 32bit driver from a 64bit runtime, have you tried setting the package to 32bit runtime?

As an alternative to struggling with those jet drivers I've started using [Microsofts OpenXML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk), its runs on 32bit while in VS and 64bit when deployed. It installs to the GAC so you can easily reference it from a script component

[Read data from excel using OpenXML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-parse-and-read-a-large-spreadsheet)